# Can I use LINQ to compare what is missing, added or updated between two collections

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have the following class. To make it so I could compare I added an Equals method:

```
 public ObjectiveDetail()
    public int ObjectiveDetailId { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return this.Equals(obj as ObjectiveDetail);
    }
    public bool Equals(ObjectiveDetail other)
    {
        if (other == null)
            return false;

        return this.Number.Equals(other.Number) &&
            (
                this.Text == other.Text ||
                this.Text != null &&
                this.Text.Equals(other.Text)
            );
    }
 }
```

I have two ICollection collections:

```
ICollection<ObjectiveDetail> _obj1; // Reference
ICollection<ObjectiveDetail> _obj2; // May have more, less or different objectDetails from the reference.
```

The common tfield with the collections is ObjectiveDetailId. Is there a way I can use three LINQ expressions to create:

- A collection of rows in _obj2 and not _obj1
- A collection of rows in _obj1 and not _obj2
- A collection of rows different between _obj1 and _obj2

Note this is similar to another question I asked earlier but I think this is a bit simpler now I have added the Equals method. uld do this?

Comment: You talk about "rows" does that mean that index of the element of the list is important? Example:
1 2 /
2 1 /
3 3
"Row" 1 and 2 are different? Or do both collections have the same values (1, 2, 3)?

Comment: The `operator ==` works well on `int` and `string` so you should just say `return this.Number == other.Number && this.Text == other.Text;` in the last statement of your `Equals` method. Don't forget to correctly override `GetHashCode()`.

Comment: Yes when I talk of rows I mean element index values. The thing for comparing the objects is ObjectiveDetailId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) to subtract sets:

```
var in2butNot1 = _obj2.Except(_obj1);
var in1butNot2 = _obj1.Except(_obj2);
```

However, this may not be what you are looking to get, because objects that have "changed" will be treated as simply "not equal" to each other.

It appears that your objects have an `ID` field. You can order the objects on that `ID`, and then traverse both collections as if you were producing a merge. This would let you detect insertions, updates, and deletions with a straightforward chain of `if`s.

You can also use IDs to decide what's common and what's changed:

```
var ids1 = new HashSet<int>(_obj1.Select(o => o.ObjectiveDetailId));
var ids2 = new HashSet<int>(_obj2.Select(o => o.ObjectiveDetailId));
var in2butNot1 = _obj2.Where(o => !ids1.Contains(o.ObjectiveDetailId));
var in1butNot2 = _obj1.Where(o => !ids2.Contains(o.ObjectiveDetailId));
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I understand the Except but can you give me an example of how I could create a list of objects that exist in both groups but that are not Equal?

Comment: I was thinking about using a For Loop. But your method of using Except looks a lot easier. Would it not be better to use your way?

Comment: @Alan No, because `Except` does not differentiates between "changed" and "inserted". If two objects are not equal, `Except` treats them as "insertions", even though their `ObjectiveDetailId`s may be identical. I'll edit some more with a slightly modified approach.

Comment: I have the rows stored in a relational table and I guess what I need to do is to generated Add, Update and Deletes with the objects as a parameter. I am not sure if this makes a difference to your suggestion. But I do I think need to get a list of deletes, updates and insertions. I think your suggestion about traversing collections may be best. I will mark this as answered and rephrase the question.

Answer (score 1):

You should always override `Equals` **and** `GetHashCode`:

- A collection of rows in _obj2 and not _obj1

  ```
  var inObj2NotInObj1 = _obj2.Except(_obj1).ToList();
  ```
- A collection of rows in _obj1 and not _obj2

  ```
  var inObj1NotInObj2 = _obj1.Except(_obj2).ToList();
  ```
- A collection of rows different between _obj1 and _obj2

Specify different, if you mean not `Equals`, that is what you have above.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean about overriding Equals?

Comment: @Alan: You have already overridden `Equals` but you should always also override `GetHashCode` then. However, that's not really part of my answer but a side-note. Use `Enumerable.Except` to get the set difference between both collection. That will use `Equals` to compare two objects.

Comment: Could you give me an example of the Enumerable.Except ?  What I mean with not Equals is when the objects have the same ObjectiveDetailId but different "Number" or "Text" field values.

Answer (score 1):

> What I mean with not Equals is when the objects have the same
>   ObjectiveDetailId but different "Number" or "Text" field values.

If you create a dictionary which maps an ID to the original (_obj1) objects, you could then look up the original with a matching ID for each new (_obj2) object and compare:

```
var oldDictionary = _obj1.ToDictionary(old => old.ObjectiveDetailId);
var updated = _obj2.Where(current => {
    ObjectiveDetail old = null;
    var isExisting = oldDictionary.TryGetValue(current.ObjectiveDetailId, out old);
    return isExisting && !old.Equals(current);
});
```