# How can I transvers two collections to find out what objects are in one and not the other?

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
 public ObjectiveDetail()
    public int ObjectiveDetailId { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return this.Equals(obj as ObjectiveDetail);
    }
    public bool Equals(ObjectiveDetail other)
    {
        if (other == null)
            return false;

        return this.Number.Equals(other.Number) &&
            (
                this.Text == other.Text ||
                this.Text != null &&
                this.Text.Equals(other.Text)
            );
    }
 }
```

I have two ICollection collections:

```
ICollection<ObjectiveDetail> _obj1; // Reference
ICollection<ObjectiveDetail> _obj2; // May have more, less or different objectDetails from the reference.
```

The common field with the collections is **ObjectiveDetailId**. How can I traverse the collections with a **for loop** to get rows that:

- Are in _obj2 and not _obj1
- Are in _obj1 and not _obj2
- Are different between _obj1 and _obj2

Note this is similar to another question I asked earlier but I think this is a bit simpler now I have added the Equals method.

Comment: You should implements `GetHashCode` method too when implement `Equals`

Comment: You asked this question 25 minutes ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162441/can-i-use-linq-to-compare-what-is-missing-added-or-updated-between-two-collecti and got an answer.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - Can you explain this more? I had another person comment on this and say it but I do not know what it means. Also why do I need to implement GetHashCode ?

Comment: he has asked this question atleast 3 times now

Comment: The question before was to use LINQ. It was a good answer and correct but I realized after the comments that I would be better in a for loop. The other time the question was asked I did not have Equals. I actually tried to delete that question but it would not let me. I don't want to pollute stackoverflow with questions so not sure why I could not delete it. I've just now highlighted the "for loop" part as you might have missed it.

Comment: You couldn't delete it because people had answered. If the answers there didn't answer your question, don't mark them as answered. Clarify what you want by commenting and/or editing your original question.

Comment: @Alan - Unless you show your research and findings before asking a question, you will find comments like this. Isn't that fair expectation. ;)

Comment: @SBirthare - agreed but often I find out I learn more / new things from the answers people give me. Those answers lead me to think some other way would be better. But I accept the answer in the LINQ question as that person gave me a good answer. It's just that he even said himself there may be a better way to do it. Hence this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use foreach

```
foreach(ObjectiveDetail obj in _obj1)
{
    if (!(_obj2.Contains(obj)))
        //add to list
}
```

Just change the logic in the if statements and the ICollection so you get the rest of the results.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did not know about .Contains.  I will accept and close this question. There were lots of comments but your answer was simple and helpful.